# Cannot get URL from Database to link

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am doing a project and would be eternally grateful for help in getting my URl's to link. I have tried looking around to no avail. I have a database (4columns). The last one  (link1) should link to videos with the specified URL.When the table comes up the URL's are not clickable (is there a way to simplify this say "click me"?). Here is my code. I've also attached an image of the table. This is really busting my brains, thanks.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","feedb933_charles","pass100","feedb933_test");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 

    echo "<table>"; 
    echo "<tr> 
    <th>topic1</th> 
    <th>subject1</th> 
    <th>link1</th> 
    </tr>"; 
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result)) { 
        $topic1 = $row["topic1"]; 
        $subject1 = $row["subject1"]; 
        $link1 = $row["link1"]; 

        echo "<tr> 
        <td>$topic1</td>
        <td>$subject1</td>
        <td>$link1</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

[Table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOlDF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `videos`";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?> 
<table>
<?php 
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result)) { 
 ?>       
    <tr> 
        <td><?php echo $row['topic1'];?></td>
        <td><?Php echo $row['subject1'];?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $row['link1']; ?>" target="_blank">Click me</td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
<table>
```

Or you can also use `do while` loop:

```
    do{
        echo '<tr>'; 
        echo      '<td>'.$row['topic1'].'</td>';
        echo      '<td>'.$row['subject1'].'</td>';
        echo      '<td><a href="'.$row['link1'].'" target="_blank">Click me</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
 } while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result);
```

I added the `target` attribute  to open the link in a new window.

Comment: Hi Mawia. thanks but it didn't work. All the data from the link1 column has disappeared . See here http://www.feedbackstuff.info/output.php

Comment: I have updated my answer. check it. And you only showed three columns in the question.

Comment: Thank you Mawia!! That worked. You are a star. It didn't work at first (but could have been a cache prob). funnily enough I also tried the Do version, but it didn't work (nothing came up) . Amazing the overall code is a lot smaller too. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks  for the target info, Nice one mate

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and i found a couple errors.

change `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","feedb933_charles","pass100","feedb933_test");` to `$con = new mysqli("localhost", "feedb933_charles", "pass100", "feedb933_test");`

Then change `if (mysqli_connect_errno())` to `if (mysqli_connect_error()) {`

Then change

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT topic1, subject1, link1 FROM videos";
```

or if you want to select one row

```
$differentvalue = ""; // value to run
$sql = "SELECT topic1, subject1, link1 FROM videos WHERE difvalue = ?";
```

`difvalue` is the value different frm the rest so the php code knows what to grab.

Using stmt means no sql injection

Add:

```
$stmt = $con->stmt_init();
if (!$stmt->prepare($sql))
{
    print "Failed to prepare statement\n";
}
else
{

}
```

Then in side `if (something) { } else { IN HERE }`

(if you have `WHERE diffvalue`) Add:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $differentvalue); // $stmt->bind_param("s", $differentvalue); if text, $stmt->bind_param("i", $differentvalue); if integer
```

Then

Add:

```
$stmt->execute();
$list = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

then outside the `if (something) { code } else { code }`

Add:

```
echo "<table><tr><th>topic1</th><th>subject1</th><th>link1</th></tr><tr>";

foreach ($list as $row => $new) {
    $html = '<td>' . $new['topic1'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $new['subject1'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $new['link1'] . '</td>';
    echo $html;
}

echo "</tr></table>";
```

If you are still having problems goto the links listed

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for a quick reply . I'll take a look at this but for now the links in the table are working.

Comment: Okay. took me a while to put this answer together, but this code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","feedb933_charles","pass100","feedb933_test");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 

    echo "<table>"; 
    echo "<tr> 
    <th>topic1</th> 
    <th>subject1</th> 
    <th>link1</th> 
    </tr>"; 
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result)) { 
        $topic1 = $row["topic1"]; 
        $subject1 = $row["subject1"]; 
        $link1 = $row["link1"]; 

        echo "<tr> 
        <td>$topic1</td>
        <td>$subject1</td>
        <a href="'.$link.'"><td>$link1</td></a>
*//this href will give u the link as u asked. //be sure you store proper url. In case of exact video name saved in column thn can make the url for your web output. //ex:<a href="http://example.com/'.$link.'.extension">*

        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Draviya for quick reply